# Trends not displayed on Twitter

Tags: twitter

I use the same Twitter account from two different machines, both equipped with Firefox (4.0 / 5.0). Usually I see the *trending topics* on the left section on the main screen. To my actual *surprise*, this works well on one machine while on the other system, I see nothing but the line

```
Following: x     Follower: y
```

and that's it. No avatar pics, no trending topics. Anyone any idea where to look for a solution?

BTW, when I execute a search, the result page shows trending topics on both machines..

---

Started playing with firebug to find out if there were any errors while loading the page, hit 'reload' and - to my surprise, now the page is complete... I'll keep my eye on that, maybe it was just a stupid caching problem...

Answer (score 2):

I have no idea if this was your issue, but FWIW Twitter seems to disable certain functionality when they are having system/performance/etc issues.

For example:  http://www.google.com/search?ie=UTF-8&q=site%3Astatus.twitter.com+disabling , which links to Twitter status updates about disabling things like Trends, "Who To Follow", etc.

Comment: *Could* be a reason. The effect is close to what you describe here. But after some additional try & error, I have the feeling, my problem is linked to the (weak) performance of that computer rather then to twitters performance... But thanks (and +1 :) )